# Why is Request.Files.Count sometimes 0 using HTML5 uploader?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, plupload

We're using plupload for users to upload files to our VPS.

Here is the plupload code:

```
 var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    browse_button: 'fileSelectorLink',
    container: 'uploadContainer',
    drop_element: 'uploadbox',
    url: '/UploadHandler.ashx',
    unique_names: true,
    multi_selection: false,
    flash_swf_url: '/scripts/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url: '/scripts/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'
});
```

He is the code for processing the request:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
  Dim runtime As String = If(context.Request("runtime") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("runtime"), "Unknown")
  If context.Request IsNot Nothing Then
    If context.Request.Files.Count > 0 Then
       Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)
       ...
    Else
       ' Throw an exception
  End If
End Sub
```

Occasionally (about 2% of the time) the exception will get thrown. Here is an example of request that threw an error:

```
Runtime: html5
Request.ContentType: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryo7JAtlhKsg8xDcQT
Request.ContentLength: 3758089
Request.ContentEncoding: System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
Request.TotalBytes: 3179067
```

The errors seem to happen across different browsers and OSs (even modern browsers), so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Plupload should fall back to other versions if browser doesn't handle async file uploads. I thought the ContentEncoding seemed odd, but it seems to always say that (maybe plupload works like that?).  The only thing that jumped out at me is that the ContentLength and TotalBytes were different, but in my local testing they were the same. Could that be a problem?

Been stuck on this issue for a few days and haven't had any good leads.

Comment: Are you testing with the same file consistently?  If different files, is there any pattern with which file types might cause the error?

Comment: Also, can we see the actual HTML?

Comment: I should have been more clear. This is in a production environment and users are uploading files. The majority of the files are .ppt, .pptx, or .pdf, but we accept a lot of file types. We don't know the file type on the errors. The HTML is standard for plupload, the plugin does most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435971/request-files-count-always-0-while-uploading-image-in-mvc-5

Comment: Thanks for the comment Casey, but I dug into it and although plupload doesn't add the name to the DOM, it does form the request properly with a name for the field when it creates the multipart-form request.

Comment: In your `If context.Request.Files.Count > 0 Then` I am not seeing Current used. For example try this: `If context.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 Then` Also can you provide your asp code?

Comment: Is it possible that the file hasn't finished uploading?

Comment: It would seem to be the case that if your TotalBytes (the actual bytes received) is less than your ContentLength (what the total number of bytes needs to be to get the whole file to the server), you are either timing out the request on the user end or somewhere in the network before your server receives the whole file, or an issue in your uploading plugin is causing the upload to terminate prematurely in certain situations.

Comment: How about proxy/firewarewall in between of the requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failures could be occurring when users abort the upload (usually indicated by "The remote host closed the connection." exceptions), are encountering network latency, perhaps from HTTP timeouts, maybe even an issue with the Plupload code.  My apologies for not being specific with the reason, however I believe I can make up for it by providing a solution that could limit issues encountered by users on your site.

Plupload contains a setting that will retry the upload upon encountering a HTTP error response.  Use the [max_retries](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Options#max_retries) setting so that in an instance where there is a "network hiccup", another attempt (or few) is/are done to retry the upload.  Of course you'll still see the exceptions, but this may prevent the users from having to click the upload button again.

Your code would then become:

```
  var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    browse_button: 'fileSelectorLink',
    max_retries: 2,
    container: 'uploadContainer',
    drop_element: 'uploadbox',
    url: '/UploadHandler.ashx',
    unique_names: true,
    multi_selection: false,
    flash_swf_url: '/scripts/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url: '/scripts/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'
});
```

Additionally, you can use a binary stream instead of multipart to post the file, which may alleviate issues with older browsers.  You control this with the [multipart](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Options#multipart) setting.